# Activerecord: Remove multiple associations via array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a has_many through:

Foo has many Bar through foo_bars

I want to pass an array of bar ids to some method on Foo that will remove the relationship in both directions-

Something like

```
foo.bars.delete([1,3,5,8])
```

However, `delete` only accepts the ID of one Model. There has got to be a way to do this in bulk and I just cannot find the answer. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Richard Peck code will not work if want to delete an array of ids.
You will get a "some association expected, got Fixnum" error.
This code will be able to do the job:

```
foo.bars.where(id: array_of_ids).delete_all
```

But the best way I found this to work is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25660566/3002847) answer comments and related to Richard answer is to use `splat` = `*` :

```
foo.bars.delete(*array_of_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question - I originally thought you'll probably be looking for [`delete_all`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-delete_all) or [`destroy_all`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-destroy_all), but after doing some testing & looking at the [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), it said you can only use `delete`

---

After testing, I found by calling `delete_all` you could get rid of all the collection data (`foo.bars.delete_all`):

[image]

---

I then tested using a naked `delete` method `foo.bars.delete(x,y)`. This worked - :

[image]

So the answer is:

`foo.bars.delete(1,2,3,4)`