# Remove object from has_many but don't delete the original record in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, collections, remove-if

I have this:

```
Post.paragraphs << new_paragraph
```

And I need to remove paragraph by id = 3, so the following deletes the record completely:

```
Post.paragraphs.find(paragraph_id).destroy
# or
Post.paragraphs.find(paragraph_id).delete
```

I just need to remove a paragraph from has_many association. I tried to use `delete` and `destroy`. Both methods completely delete records from the associated tables. How can I just remove them from the "container"?

Comment: Please note, that I forgot to remove the dependent: destroy. Anyway the answers below are great.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You should not use the `delete` method on the `Paragraph`object, but instead use the delete method of `paragraphs` relation, like this:

```
post.paragraphs.delete(Paragraph.find(paragraph_id))
```

Comment: you can omit `Paragraph` and use `post.paragraphs.delete(paragraph_id)`. You can pass `Fixnum` or `String` values, it finds the records responding to the `id` and executes `delete` on them.

Comment: @Зелёный is there a way to make it work with an array of ids?

Comment: @valk pass splat(*) array to delete method. Something like: `array = [1,2,3,4]` and now `post.paragraphs.delete(*array)` [read about it](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy/delete)

Comment: Doesn't this actually perform `delete` on the record, removing it from the database?  The OP is asking how to remove the item from the array, not delete from the database.

Comment: The record is not removed from the database, unless `dependant: :destroy` has been set in the `has_many` relation